# how to get process name and date time stamp in native C++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

In Native C++, how can I get the current process Name and date time. I am not a C++ programmer.

In C#, it is very trivial to do it like this:

Process name:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
```

Date Time:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss.ff")
```

How can they be retrieved in C++ native?

Comment: For Windows only?  Tag the q if so

Comment: OK I've added the requisite tags for you

Comment: So are you basically asking for the Win32 api to do it which is not really C++ question at all?

Comment: @Lap - not so, perhaps there is Boost or similar that can do the D&T part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the name of the current process you can use [`GetModuleFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
char exe_path[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, exe_path, MAX_PATH);
```

You can then extract the part of `exe_path` after the last `\` character.

To get the current time, you can use [`std::time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time).

Comment: 'GetModuleFileNameW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [260]' to 'LPWCH'

Comment: Your must be targeting UNICODE in your build. Either use `wchar_t` instead of `char` or explicitly use the ANSI version `GetModuleFileNameA`.

Comment: Thanks. correctly, I got the full path including the extension. thanks

Comment: for the time, do you know how to get the specific date time format: "yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss.ff"

Comment: You could use [strftime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

**GetSystemTime**

**Syntax**

```
void WINAPI GetSystemTime(
  __out  LPSYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime
);
```

**Parameters:**  lpSystemTime [out]

> A pointer to a SYSTEMTIME structure to receive the current system date
>   and time. The lpSystemTime parameter must not be NULL. Using NULL will
>   result in an access violation.

**Return value:** This function does not return a value or provide extended error information.

**Remarks:** To set the current system date and time, use the SetSystemTime function.

**Requirements:** Minimum supported client Windows 2000 Professional

**Minimum supported server:** Windows 2000 Server

**Header :** Winbase.h (include Windows.h)

**Library :** Kernel32.lib

**DLL :** Kernel32.dll

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**And for process name:**

[QueryFullProcessImageName function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[GetModuleFileNameEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Process and Thread Functions can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Process name:

```
char name[256];
GetProcessImageFileName(GetCurrentProcess(),name,256);
```

You can also get it from the command-line arguments

And for the date use localtime() from time.h, example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/)

Comment: I cant find: GetProcessImageFileName in C++?

Comment: @olidev yes, you need to include windows.h

Comment: @olidev oh, sorry, i forgot about that, this function also needs Psapi.h and Psapi.lib as static library;
you can also use GetModuleFileName, but it will retrieve the full path